# Adding a reg key from vb

Tags: vb.net, cmd, key, registry

I have to add a reg key from a vb exe.

I run this string form cmd and work fine.

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "bit" /t REG_SZ /d C:\ProgramData\i2.exe
```

So in a vb file i did this:

```
Shell("REG ADD ""HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"" /v ""bit"" /t REG_SZ /d C:\ProgramData\i2.exe")
```

But this add a reg key in a wrong path.

Maybe is a sintax problem. Where i fail? There is a command more correct in vb?

Comment: My crystal ball says that this ends up in HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node instead.  Because your program runs a 32-bit process so it uses the 32-bit version of Reg.exe.  Which writes to the "wrong" key, the one that 32-bit apps use.  More than one way to fix this, including doing nothing, the next simplest way is to change your project's Platform target to AnyCPU.

Answer (score 0):

.NET Framework 4 has `RegistryKey` class that is capable of handling 32/64 bit registry access, in a way that is independent of your target platform:

```
RegistryKey regkey =
    RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(
        RegistryHive.LocalMachine,
        RegistryView.Registry64)
    .OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE")
```

More info can be found here http://sander.rijken.info/post/46536267427/reading-64-bit-registry-from-32bit-app

If you want to know if the system is 32 or 64 bit:

```
Private is64BitProcess As Boolean = (IntPtr.Size = 8)
Private is64BitOperatingSystem As Boolean = is64BitProcess OrElse InternalCheckIsWow64()

<DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Winapi)> _
Public Shared Function IsWow64Process( _
    ByVal hProcess As System.IntPtr, _
    ByRef wow64Process As Boolean) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean

End Function

Public Shared Function InternalCheckIsWow64() As Boolean
    If (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major = 5 AndAlso Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor >= 1) OrElse Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6 Then
        Using p As Process = Process.GetCurrentProcess()
            Dim retVal As Boolean
            If Not IsWow64Process(p.Handle, retVal) Then
                Return False
            End If
            Return retVal
        End Using
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```